# (D3) Data Driven Documents -- Transition Repetition

Tags: d3.js, transition, data-driven

I've looked for over 3 hours now trying to find a way to chain transitions indefinitely...

My only solution is wrapping the code in a function, then repeatedly calling the function with setInterval or waiting for the transition 'end' event

Example one liner:

```
d3.selectAll('circle').data([1,2,3]).enter().append('circle').attr('cy':function(d){return d * 100},'cx':function(){Math.random() * window.innerWidth},'r':'10px')

//sets initial locations for circles that are created to match data array

.transition().attr('cy':function(){Math.random() * window.innerHeight},'cx':function(){Math.random() * window.innerWidth}})
.transition().attr('cy':function(){Math.random() * window.innerHeight},'cx':function(){Math.random() * window.innerWidth}})
.transition().attr('cy':function(){Math.random() * window.innerHeight},'cx':function(){Math.random() * window.innerWidth}})
.transition().attr('cy':function(){Math.random() * window.innerHeight},'cx':function(){Math.random() * window.innerWidth}})
.transition().attr('cy':function(){Math.random() * window.innerHeight},'cx':function(){Math.random() * window.innerWidth}})

//I'm looking for something that can repeat the transition without using setInterval)
```

Comment: What's wrong with waiting for the transition end event, and then invoking another transition?

Comment: I want to invoke the same transition without leaving the chain of commands. I want to be able to invoke the last N steps, every few seconds (whether that's a transition or just a repeat binding of some data object to the DOM element when the data changes)

Answer (score 0):

One way or another, I think you're going to have to wrap your transition settings in a function, so that you can call it recursively.  However, @Jon S. is right, you can use the transition's "end" event instead of a separate timer.

The complication is that the callback function in `transition.each("end", callback)` is (as the method name suggests) called for *each* element in the array.  A simple check can make sure the recursion only happens once, for the first element, and doesn't branch indefinitely.

Here's an example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/UD9ng/1/

Key code:

```
var moving = false;

function move(selection) {

    moving = true;
    selection.transition().duration(5000).ease("sin-in-out")
        .attr("cx", function(){return Math.random()*width;})
        .attr("cy", function(){return Math.random()*height;})
        //.call(move); //stack overflow error!
        .each("end", function(d,i){ 
            if (!i) circles.call(move); //only run for i==0
        });

}
```

As you can see from the comments, I tried using the transition's `.call()` method (which invokes a function once for the entire transition object), but there is no way currently to delay that call until the end of the transition, so repeated sub-transition calls were being added to a queue until the console spit out an error with a huge stack trace behind it.  The weird thing was, it didn't look like anything was wrong, since all the queued-up transitions were still moving smoothly -- but they would have run out of transitions eventually.

The each/end approach -- with the recursive function called on the original selection -- replaces the finished transition instead of chaining to it, so it can continue indefinitely without consuming increasing resources.

Comment: Yea, I know that I can do this but I want to avoid the function declaration, not just the "setInterval(move,1000)"

Comment: Well, in that case, the answer to your question is no, it's not possible with transitions.  Transitions are designed to go from one state to another, not for indefinite animations.

Comment: P.S.  Maybe if you updated the question with more specific examples of why you don't think a function call will work, then we could help you make it happen.